# AWS ec2 ubuntu server cannot get updates

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-18.04

I have an AWS ec2 set up for a web server. The server is running Ubuntu 18.04 and Nginx. It suddenly went out of internet access after my freedom domain registration expired. I doubt it is related to Freenom expiration as I have forgotten to renew domain registration before, but I didn't lose internet connection like this time.

I can ssh into my ec2 with something like

```
ssh -i "dummy.pem" ubuntu@ec2-3-10-14-99.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

but I had an error message as below indicating no internet connection.

> Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts.
> Check your Internet connection or proxy settings

However, it seems that I can ping google. But sudo apt update does not work. It returns errors as follows

> Err:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic InRelease
> Cannot initiate the connection to ppa.launchpad.net:80
> (2620:2d:4000:1::3e). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could
> not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (185.125.190.52), connection timed
> out Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease
> Cannot initiate the connection to ppa.launchpad.net:80
> (2620:2d:4000:1::3e). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) ...

It probably has nothing to do with the security settings. Nothing has changed regarding that. All outbound traffic is allowed and ports 22,80,443 are opened for inbound traffic.

I have only one more security group besides the default one. And the ec2 instance is using a security group (launch-wizard-1) with the NACL as shown [here](https://www.samuelcheng.info/debug.png)

Btw, wget seems to fail as well.

```
wget www.google.com
```

struggles to finish and ultimately return unreachable error.

> --2022-08-15 22:29:08--  http://www.google.com/ Resolving [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) ([www.google.com](http://www.google.com))... 142.250.191.132,
> ...
> ([www.google.com](http://www.google.com))|2607:f8b0:4009:818::2004|:80... failed: Network is
> unreachable.

Any suggestion to troubleshoot the problem is welcome!

Comment: I updated the title to more accurately reflect your problem, as the server has an internet connection, the problem appears to be with Ubuntu updates. Please edit your question to include the full text of what happens when you run "apt update". You do not need inbound security groups open unless it's a public web server, you need outbound on ports 80 and 443. NACLs should allow all traffic in and out while testing. Please include screenshots of your NACLs and security group when you edit your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I edited the question to include NACLs and responses from "apt update." Unfortunately, I have to cut my response as I don't have enough reputation to include everything as it contains more than ten links.

Comment: Please include security groups. There's probably a way to remove the links - maybe remove the http / https part. It looks to me like you've got problems with either your security groups or routing. I also note that you have IPv6 enabled, which is fine, but check you've specifically routed IPv6 as well as IPv4.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'm not exactly sure what to show for security groups. So I tried to clarify my security group setup. I only have one group (launch-wizard-1) besides the default one and the ec2 is attached to the security group (launch-wizard-1) with the given NACL.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your EC2 instance is trying to access servers using IPv6, but you have no outbound IPv6 security group rules. Try adding a new security group rule "::/0" to 0.0.0.0/0 to your outbound SG. Also ensure IPv6 is in your route table.

Your link above labeled "NACL" is actually showing security groups. You should also check your Network ACLs, which are different from security groups.

AWS is quite a complex enterprise system. Deploying on AWS without training usually means you miss some things and security is compromised. For example, you have a lot of inbound ports to your EC2 instance open to the world, including SSH, which is not good practice. Suggest you close any inbound SG ports you don't need open.

Comment: I created another 18.04 instance with the same security group and the new instance does not have any connection issue. Maybe the problem is not AWS security setting but the ubuntu instance got corrupted. How can one debug Ubuntu connection? I can ping but I cannot wget. And is it possible to backup anything of an AWS instance when I don't have connection. If I can pull out some important files, I don't mind terminating the instance and creating a new one. It may be easier.

Comment: Ah well, it was a reasonable guess. I still wonder if it's something to do with IPv6, maybe the new OS is configured for IPv4. You can do a snapshot of your old volume, or simply stop the instance, detach the EBS volume from the old instance, and attach it as a data volume to the new instance. You can then copy the files over and optionally then detach and delete the old volume.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I tried adding ipv6 to the security group but couldn't connect. Eventually, as you suggested, I just attached the original EBS volume to the new instance and copy the files. At least the problem is solved now! Even though still not sure what the problem was. But I probably won't worry about it until it happens again.

Comment: That's an odd problem. Like you said, likely a problem within the OS.